# Change row to 0 based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
   1     0      1         2
   2     2      3         1
   3     8      2         9
```

Expected output:

```
       1     0      1         0
       2     2      3         0
       3     8      2         9
```

My initial thought process for this is

```
     df = np.where(df['Reported'] >= df['Goal'], df['Score'] = 0, df['Score']
```

This isn't working as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, just replace `df['Score'] = 0` with `0` for passed condition and assign the output to `df.Score` col.

```
df.Score = np.where(df['Reported'] >= df['Goal'],0, df['Score'] )
```

**Output**

```
    ID  Goal    Reported    Score
0   1   0       1           0
1   2   2       3           0
2   3   8       2           9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loc` method for indexing :

```
df.loc[df['Reported'] >= df['Goal'],'Score'] = 0
```